# How to call the library in Python to achieve the same function as dctmtx(N) in matlab

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, dct

In Python, `dct()` in scipy is similar to `dct2()` in matlab, so is there a library similar to dctmtx in matlab in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the same result as `D = dctmtx(n)` in Matlab, you can use

```
D = dct(np.eye(n), norm='ortho', axis=0)
```

Paul Panzer's suggestion should also work fine, and might even be a bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy enough to build it yourself:

```
# pick a size
N = 99

# build the matrix
n, k = np.ogrid[1:2*N+1:2, :N]
dctmtx = 2 * np.cos(np.pi/(2*N) * n * k)

# create random data for testing 
x = np.random.normal(size=(N, N))

# check
from scipy import fftpack
np.allclose(fftpack.dctn(x), dctm.T @ x @ dctm)
# True
```

Note: scaling my be subject to convention. Here I chose one to exactly match `scipy.fftpack.dctn`; matlab may or may not use the same scaling.